# Utilizar foreach em checkbox de uma tabela

Tags: php, mysqli, checkbox, table, foreach

No código que estou criando há uma exibição de todos os usuários do site em uma tabela html, até  ai tudo certo, porem ao selecionar múltiplos checkbox para excluir vários usuários do site simplesmente nada acontece apenas a página atualiza mas os dados ainda continuam lá, código que criei:

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
session_start();
?>
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Sel.
                </th>
                <th>
                    ID
                </th>
                <th>
                    Permissão
                </th>
                <th>
                    Status
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php
            $select = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY ID ASC");
            $row = $select->num_rows;
            if ( $row > 0 ) {
                while ($get = $select->fetch_array()) {
                $data_mysql = $get["LogouUltimoSite"];
                $timestamp = strtotime($data_mysql);
                $status = $get["Status"];
                $permissao = $get["Permissao"];
       ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="chk[]" value="<?= $get["ID"] ?>"/>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?= $get["ID"] ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        if ( $permissao == 0 ) {
                            echo("Membro");
                        } else {
                            echo("Admin.");
                        }
                   ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?php
                        if ( $status == 0 ) {
                            echo("Normal");
                        } else {
                            echo("Banido");
                        }
                    ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <?php
             }
         } else {
         ?>
            <h4> Não existe nenhum usuário ! </h4>
         <?php
     }
         ?>
        </tbody>
     </table>
    <form method="POST">
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="button" value="Excluir"/>
    </form>
    <?php
     $chk = $_POST["chk"];
     if ( isset($_POST["button"]) ) {
         foreach ($chk as $item) {
            $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM usuarios WHERE ID='" . $item . "'");
            $mysqli->close();
     }
}
?>
```

Desde já agradeço caso possam me ajudar.

> Pode ser que no código haja alguma parte faltando, caso isso ocorra foi pelo fato de ter o cortado para que não ficasse muito extenso !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seus checkboxes estão sendo gerados antes de abrir do `form`, por isso não são enviados.

Passe o `<form method="POST">` mais para cima:

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
session_start();
?>

<form method="POST">      <!-- BASICAMENTE MUDAMOS ESSA LINHA DE LUGAR -->
    <table width="100%">
        <thead>

        ... AQUI VAI A GERACAO DOS CHECKBOXES ...

        </tbody>
     </table>
     <input class="button" type="submit" name="button" value="Excluir"/>
 </form>
 <?php
     if ( isset($_POST["button"]) ) {
        $chk = $_POST["chk"];

     ...
```